# Buttons on popup.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Its possible to create an Action in popup.html ? 
To simplify, when the user click on the button, move to a 'new' popup.html..

I'm trying to create a menu using buttons to indicate Autors and when clicked result informations about the autors.

Follow my project so far..

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Autors info",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "123",
  "browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 500px;
                background-color: #ADD8E6;
            }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h1>Info Autors</h1>
        <h3>Click bellow to check autors story:</h3>

        <button type="button" id="create">JRR Tolken</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? A popup can navigate to a new document, or it can render new content, just like any other web page or extension page.

Comment: @JoshLee i just need to keep the display static, on the same format. Which one is the simplest way? rendering or calling another .html?

Comment: Simplest for whom? It depends.